# How to assign div to text

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have some text which I want to change the color of so I assigned a div class to it, `donate` Like so:

```
<div class="entry-content">
<div class="donate"><strong>Adsler.co.uk is an entirely free 
site, enabling users to post, view and apply for jobs, post, view 
and respond to classifieds, post, view and attend events, in 
addition to a dating service. We try to keep Adsler free from Google 
ads and the site is maintained entirely at the owners expense.</p>
<p>So, if you have enjoyed using Adsler, or have found it beneficial 
in some way, you are free to make a donation, or not &#8211; as you 
see fit. There is absolutely no obligation or pressure to do so and 
you are more than welcome to continue using the site without 
donating.</p>
<p>If you do wish to donate, however, then you can donate as much or 
as little as you want via the form below.</p>
<p>Wishing you a pleasant day from all at Adsler.co.uk.<br />
</strong></div><p>*N.B. Donating does not give you editorial or any 
other rights. All donations are non-refundable. For technical 
reasons, the only current donation amount is $5.</strong></div>
```

Then I used css:

```
.donate {color: yellow !important;}
```

Doesn't work. What happens is that the text flashes yellow for a second and then turns back to black. Also, have used `<strong>`but only half of textis defined as `strong`, the other half not.

Page for clarification: https://adsler.co.uk/if-you-enjoyed-using-the-site/

This failing, I used specificity.

```
.entry-content>.donate 
{color:yellow! important;}
```

Nothing.

Comment: what is the exact text that should be yellow ? 
the whole text or only that inside `.donate` div ?

Comment: Yes, everything inside `donate`

Comment: so this should work fine for you: `.donate {color: yellow !important;}`. it worked fine when i tested it. maybe there is other css code that is overriding this property.

Comment: i can add an answer with working code bt i think the problem is that maybe  other css code is overriding this

Comment: @kareem it can't be because I'm using `important`

Comment: you can check the answer, i've tested it in your page via inspect and it worked fine

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You have a closing `</p>` without an opening `<p>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.donate {color: yellow}` should work fine. but once your page have `* {color: #000000}` loaded in your page,  its overriding the color.

you cant fix it by adding `!important` so you have two choices:

1- remove `* {color: #000000}` from css

2- add this css:

```
.donate, .donate * { 
color: yellow
}
```

`.donate *` is to change the color to `.donate` and all its childs

Comment: That worked except the last little bit is still black starting with `NB` and ending with `$5`

Comment: because it's outside the div `.donate` you are closing the div before this text check your code and wrap this text inside `.donate` div

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution. All text are looking yellow now.

```css
.donate {color: yellow !important;}
```

```html
<div class="entry-content">
<div class="donate">Adsler.co.uk is an entirely free 
site, enabling users to post, view and apply for jobs, post, view 
and respond to classifieds, post, view and attend events, in 
addition to a dating service. We try to keep Adsler free from Google 
ads and the site is maintained entirely at the owners expense.
<p>So, if you have enjoyed using Adsler, or have found it beneficial 
in some way, you are free to make a donation, or not &#8211; as you 
see fit. There is absolutely no obligation or pressure to do so and 
you are more than welcome to continue using the site without 
donating.</p>
<p>If you do wish to donate, however, then you can donate as much or 
as little as you want via the form below.</p>
<p>Wishing you a pleasant day from all at Adsler.co.uk.</p><br>
<p>*N.B. Donating does not give you editorial or any 
other rights. All donations are non-refundable. For technical 
reasons, the only current donation amount is $5.</p></div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but 1. It removes `strong` and 2, only first part of text is yellow. See page https://adsler.co.uk/if-you-enjoyed-using-the-site/